# Gas ranges and the need for electicity

Tags: kitchens

Does a gas range need any electicity to keep or start the pilot light going? or if there is a power failure will the gas range still work?

Answer (score 3):

A gas range with a pilot light doesn't need electricity because it has a pilot light. A gas range with electric ignition needs electricity for the electric ignitors. If the power goes out, an electrically-ignited range will work just fine because you can simply light the gas yourself with a match.

Comment: May be obvious, but if you hear a "tick tick tick" sound when turning on a burner, the stove has electric ignition.  If you happen to be in a new place and you're not sure...

Comment: And the oven of most non-pilot-light gas ranges will **not** work in a power outage due to the design of the non-pilot-light used there.